# Update a Numpy 1D array B in each loop to solve the matrix expression A*x = B

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to solve `x` from sparse matrix expression `A*x = B` in loops, where `A` is a Scipy CSC sparse-matrix and `B` is Numpy 1D array. Both `A` and `B` are large about 500K rows. Basically, I need to update `B` in each loop. So the speed to update `B` is critical. Right now, my way is to define `csc_matrix` in each loop, and then convert it to 1D Numpy array as below which is really expensive in terms of time:

```
B = csc_matrix((data,(row, col)),shape=(500000, 1), dtype='complex128').toarray()[:,0];
```

Please note:

- `row` has lots of the repeated index, such as `[0,1,2,0,2,2,3,3....],`
- `col` is `[0,0, 0,.......0];`

**Is there fast way to update B in each loop?**

Comment: What the loop does? Does it updates `data`? Same for `row`? Are `data` and `row`/`col` Numpy arrays?

Comment: Jerome, thanks for the reply. Yes, the each loop is to update data with the solved x. There are some algorithm behind it. row and col are same and no change for each loop. data, row and col are Numpy arrays. I just wonder: without using numba, is there fast way to update B? I just want to reduce dependency as possible as I can.

Comment: `np.add.at` might work to create the array with the desired summation of duplicates.

Comment: hpaulj, thanks for the info. I have tried np.add.at, but it is still expensive in terms of time. It didn't improve too much.

Comment: Why do you need to invent your own solver instead of using one of the many solvers that already exist for this?

Comment: CJR, I don't know where your question came from. I didn't invent my own solver but using  Scipy csc_matrix which you can see the post. This has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: I mean the first sentence is that you're solving Ax=B, so is there a reason you aren't just using [spsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html)? Or any of the other solvers? In scipy or in blas or whatever? I'm just curious cause I'd assume even using an iterative solver the problem you're encountering should be handled in the solver and you shouldn't have to write much code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `col` contains only zeros, `data`/`row`/`col` are Numpy arrays and you want `B` stored as a Numpy array. You can use **Numba** to generate `B` efficiently. Here is how:

```py
import numba

# Works in-place to avoid any slow allocation in the critical loop.
# Note that the type of row may be different.
@nb.njit(void(nb.complex128[:], nb.complex128[:], nb.int64[:]))
def updateVector(B, data, row):
    B.fill(0.)
    for i in range(len(row)):
        B[row[i]] += data[i]
```

`updateVector` update the value of `B` in-place. This assume `B` has been allocated at the correct size before (using for example `B = np.empty(500000, dtype=np.complex128)`).

On my machine this is **14 times faster** with the following configuration:

```py
row = np.random.randint(0, 500000, size=100000)
col = np.zeros(100000, dtype=np.int64)
data = np.random.rand(100000) + np.random.rand(100000) * 1j
```